# How it work Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory

Tags: customer, shipping-address, customer-address, interface, address-interface

I am analysising Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress

By the way I am facing with $addressDataObject = $this->addressDataFactory->create(); in 567 line

$this->addressDataFactory this was injected from Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory

I want to see Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory interface file
However this file isn't existed its directory

[image]

How can I make sense
Hope to you help me

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Factory classes are generated automatically and you can find them in `generated` folder from your Magento installation location.

Basically, you should have a `<magento_proj>/generated/code/Magento/Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory.php` file in there.